# How to add crossfade animation to GenericRequestBuilder in Glide

Tags: java, android, android-glide

I load images with this builder

```
Glide.with(ctx)
    .using(new FileModelLoader(downlaoder), FilePath.class)
    .from(FileReference.class)
    .as(Bitmap.class)
    .decoder(new FilePathDecoder(ctx))
    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE);
```

The problem is: there is no crossfade animation.
So how do i return it?

I need a custom ResourceDecoder because for some models  I have to load webp with transparancy which is not supported on all android versions.

So my question is how do I return crossfadeAnimation to my GenericRequestBuilder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't a built in way to cross fade Bitmaps. You can however, use a custom [BitmapImageViewTarget](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/360/com/bumptech/glide/request/target/BitmapImageViewTarget.html), and use a [TransitionDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/TransitionDrawable.html) in `onResourceReady()` to cross fade. If you want to avoid applying the cross fade when the resource is cached, you can alternatively do the same thing in `onResourceReady` in a [RequestListener](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/360/com/bumptech/glide/request/RequestListener.html) which will give you that information.

The code Glide uses to [apply cross fades internally](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/blob/3.0/library/src/main/java/com/bumptech/glide/request/animation/DrawableCrossFadeViewAnimation.java#L44) may also be helpful.

Also since `TransitionDrawable` only works on `Drawables`, you will need to wrap your `Bitmap` in a [BitmapDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html#BitmapDrawable(android.content.res.Resources,%20android.graphics.Bitmap)) first.