# Fading animation not working when an image is loaded with .asBitmap()

Tags: android, android-animation, android-imageview, android-glide

I have this code

```
Glide
            .with(this)
            .load(mUrl)
            .asBitmap()
            .thumbnail(Glide
                    .with(this)
                    .load(mPreviewUrl)
                    .asBitmap()
                    .animate(R.anim.fade_in))
            .listener(new RequestListener<String, Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<Bitmap> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, String model, Target<Bitmap> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL, Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL) {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation glideAnimation) {
                    mWallpaperImageView.setImageBitmap(resource);
                    createPaletteAsync(resource);
                }
            });
```

This downloads an image and returns a `Bitmap` object, which then I use to generate a palette of colour with the `Palette` library. I also want to load the bitmap in an `ImageView`, and I do that with `mWallpaperImageView.setImageBitmap(resource)` which loads the image without any fading or animation to smooth out the loading.

If I use glide like this:

```
Glide.with(this)
            .load(mUrl)
            .crossFade(500)
            .into(mImageView)
```

then the image appears with fading but then I don't have a `Bitmap` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30081212/how-to-add-crossfade-animation-to-genericrequestbuilder-in-glide),

> Unfortunately, there isn't a built in way to cross fade Bitmaps. You
>   can however, use a custom BitmapImageViewTarget, and use a
>   TransitionDrawable in onResourceReady() to cross fade.

Fortunately, there's a trick to enable [fading effect with bitmap in Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/605).

For this you will need two classes,

**FadingDrawable**

```
final public class FadingDrawable extends BitmapDrawable {
    // Only accessed from main thread.
    private static final float FADE_DURATION = 200; //ms
    private final float density;
    Drawable placeholder;
    long startTimeMillis;
    boolean animating;
    int alpha = 0xFF;

    FadingDrawable(Context context, Bitmap bitmap, Drawable placeholder) {
        super(context.getResources(), bitmap);

        this.density = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

        this.placeholder = placeholder;
        animating = true;
        startTimeMillis = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    }

    /**
     * Create or update the drawable on the target {@link android.widget.ImageView} to display the supplied bitmap
     * image.
     */
    static public void setBitmap(ImageView target, Context context, Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (bitmap != null && !bitmap.isRecycled()) {
            Drawable placeholder = target.getDrawable();
            if (placeholder instanceof AnimationDrawable) {
                ((AnimationDrawable) placeholder).stop();
            }
            FadingDrawable drawable = new FadingDrawable(context, bitmap, placeholder);

            //this will avoid OverDraw
            //target.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
            //target.setBackgroundColor(0);

            target.setImageDrawable(drawable);

        }
    }

    /**
     * Create or update the drawable on the target {@link android.widget.ImageView} to display the supplied
     * placeholder image.
     */
    static void setPlaceholder(ImageView target, Drawable placeholderDrawable) {
        target.setImageDrawable(placeholderDrawable);
        if (target.getDrawable() instanceof AnimationDrawable) {
            ((AnimationDrawable) target.getDrawable()).start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (!animating) {
            super.draw(canvas);
        } else {
            float normalized = (SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTimeMillis) / FADE_DURATION;
            if (normalized >= 1f) {
                animating = false;
                placeholder = null;
                super.draw(canvas);
            } else {
                if (placeholder != null) {
                    placeholder.draw(canvas);
                }

                int partialAlpha = (int) (alpha * normalized);
                super.setAlpha(partialAlpha);
                super.draw(canvas);
                super.setAlpha(alpha);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD_MR1) {
                    invalidateSelf();
                }
            }
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
        this.alpha = alpha;
        if (placeholder != null) {
            placeholder.setAlpha(alpha);
        }
        super.setAlpha(alpha);
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
        if (placeholder != null) {
            placeholder.setColorFilter(cf);
        }
        super.setColorFilter(cf);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBoundsChange(Rect bounds) {
        if (placeholder != null) {
            placeholder.setBounds(bounds);
        }
        super.onBoundsChange(bounds);
    }
}
```

and **GlideImageView**

```
public class GlideImageView extends AppCompatImageView {
    public GlideImageView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public GlideImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public GlideImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        Drawable placeholder = getDrawable();
        if (placeholder instanceof AnimationDrawable) {
            ((AnimationDrawable) placeholder).stop();
            Glide.clear(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (bitmap != null) FadingDrawable.setBitmap(this, getContext(), bitmap);
    }

    public void setImageBitmapWithoutAnimation(Bitmap bitmap) {
        super.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

Now change your **mWallpaperImageView** from `ImageView` to

```
<com.yourpackage.GlideImageView
    android:id="@+id/mWallpaperImageView" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

And finally remove all external animation effect from Glide configuration,

```
Glide
     .with(this)
     .load(mUrl)
     .asBitmap()
     .thumbnail(Glide
                    .with(this)
                    .load(mPreviewUrl)
                    .asBitmap()
            .listener(new RequestListener<String, Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<Bitmap> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, String model, Target<Bitmap> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL, Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL) {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation glideAnimation) {
                    mWallpaperImageView.setImageBitmap(resource);
                    createPaletteAsync(resource);
                }
            });
```

Tested and working properly!

Comment: I can't use both .crossFade and .asBitmap, it gives an error.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work, see I updated my question with the actual code. Might it be because it's applied to a thumbnail?

Comment: Glide.clear(this) method is deprecated, so which method is available now **(for 4.4.0 version)** ? @ProkashSarkar

Answer (score 0):

You can use the value of the alpha of an image to create a fade in or fade out effect:

In Java

```
yourimage.animate().setAlpha(0f).setDuration(2000);
```

given that the image's alpha starts with alpha =1 (not transparent).
so the image will disappear (transparent) during 2 seconds

Comment: Two things: i want the image to fade in and not fade out, and secondly what should I pass as "yourimage"? Thanks.

Comment: @user11230

1.then  before doing the animation set the alpha of the image to 0f . when you use animate set the alpha to 1f.

2.an image view

Comment: @RimaIbrahim If you animate from 0 alpha you lose your placeholder immediately. As a result the placeholder will flash to empty space and then new bitmap fades in. That doesn't look good.